# How to Change R locale globally in Ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu, locale

My Ubuntu server is writing CSV files and plots with wrong encodings.

On OS X machines one possibility to set locale globally is

```
system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")
```

I have this output after saving my plot as png:

[image]

This is *not* a ggplot2 question. So what intrigues me is that on RStudio the plot is seen *correctly* :S

[image]

How can I set an option so that R works with `en_US.UTF-8` for RStudio, scripts on terminal, etc?

Answer (score 0):

To set the localization of R for a user in Ubuntu you can create a text file names `.Renviron` and home folder of the user and add this line:

```
LANGUAGE="en_US.utf8"
```

After restarting R, RStudio or whichever "front-end" you are using your R uses this locale.

For background information see:

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Locales

Answer (score 0):

for Ubuntu server in docker running following commands worked for me:

```
locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
update-locale LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.Renviron
```